# Spacing of QToolButton in a QDialog

Tags: qt, layout, qdialog

I have a QDialog with QToolButton's. All QToolButton's are grouped in couples in QHBoxLayout, which are then added to a QVBoxLayout as final layout.

I have used the QVBoxLayout.spacing(0) to remove spacing, but i still see empty space between the border of the QDialog and the QToolButton.
I tried stylesheet to set padding and margin at zero (for QDialog) as well as te setContentMargin (0,0,0,0). Nothing works. Are there other ways? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the size policy for your buttons?

Comment: yes but nothing changes, I keep having lot of empty space

Comment: Try to set zero margins for your `QToolButton`s with `QWidget::setContentsMargins(int, int, int, int)`

Comment: I just tried setContentsMargins(int, int, int, int)  on the main layout (the one declared in set layout) and it worked. Thanks.